# Java Error; could not resolve variable name

Tags: java

Forgive me for asking a very basic question, I've only just begun learning Java and something doesn't make much sense to me. I was working on some simple practice problems and then I come across this one:

> Given a string, we'll say that the front is the first 3 chars of the string. If the string length is less than 3, the front is whatever is there. Return a new string which is 3 copies of the front.

[Here is the link](http://codingbat.com/prob/p136351) for anyone interested. This didn't look hard, so I wrote this;

```
public String front3(String str){
  if (str.length() < 3){
    String front = str;
  } else {
    String front = str.substring(0, 3);
  }
  return front + front + front;
}
```

This doesn't run. Instead it gives an exception saying the name `front` could not be resolved. What? Why would this happen, either way `String front` is getting initialized in either the if block or the else block, to a strictly Pythonic coder this is doesn't make sense. The example code showed how I have to have the line `String front;` as the second line, to initialize an empty string.

What under the hood is going on that would cause this not to work in Java? Try to explain it in a way that a Pythonista would understand! :)

Also I assume I'm going to get downvoted into oblivion as I'm sure this is a common problem that many beginners run into, and there is probably already an answer somewhere on SO.

Comment: you need to learn about variable scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scope of a declared variable is limited to the block in which it's located, so `front` immediately goes out of scope as soon as it's initialized.

Any local variable declared inside any `{}`, even the `{}` for an if statement, is not visible outside those `{}`.

Declare it before the `if` so it remains in scope for the duration of the method.

```
String front;
if (str.length() < 3){
  front = str;
} else {
  front = str.substring(0, 3);
}
```

Comment: Wow, thats bizarre to me. So I assume this goes for ANY block in Java?

Comment: That's right.  Any local variable declared inside any `{}`, even the `{}` for an `if` statement, is not visible outside those `{}`.

Comment: @rgettman you should include that comment in your answer as a precursor to the code sample. Very concise answer to a well asked question.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your variable outside the if.

```
public String front3(String str){
  String front;
  if (str.length() < 3){
    front = str;
  } else {
    front = str.substring(0, 3);
  }
  return front + front + front;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. Read it one more time ;)